# write MySQL searching for more than one value in a column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Division, 
    EffectiveDate, 
    PM, 
    case Status 
        when 0 then 'Dead'
        when 1 then 'Active'
        when 2 then 'Job'
        when 3 then 'Pending'
        when 4 then 'Sales Lead'
        when 5 then 'Budget'
        when 6 then 'Change Order'
    end as Status, 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= '2015-06-01'
AND Status = 6
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
;
```

i need to return all the values with a status of 6 OR 2

i tried writing `AND Status = 6 or 2` but that doesnt work =/
is this accomplished by joining tables or is there a simpler way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Division, 
    EffectiveDate, 
    PM, 
    case Status 
        when 0 then 'Dead'
        when 1 then 'Active'
        when 2 then 'Job'
        when 3 then 'Pending'
        when 4 then 'Sales Lead'
        when 5 then 'Budget'
        when 6 then 'Change Order'
    end as Status, 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= '2015-06-01'
AND ( Status = 6 OR Status = 2 )
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you just need a `OR` statement with `Status = 2`.

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Division, 
    EffectiveDate, 
    PM, 
    case Status 
        when 0 then 'Dead'
        when 1 then 'Active'
        when 2 then 'Job'
        when 3 then 'Pending'
        when 4 then 'Sales Lead'
        when 5 then 'Budget'
        when 6 then 'Change Order'
    end as Status, 
    Name, 
    Address, 
    ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= '2015-06-01'
AND (Status = 2 OR Status = 6)
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
;
```

Here is some more [info](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php).

Answer (score 0):

You want either IN or OR -

```
AND Status IN (6, 2)

AND Status = 6 OR Status = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN in your query. Tyr this :

```
SELECT 
ID, 
Division, 
EffectiveDate, 
PM, 
case Status 
    when 0 then 'Dead'
    when 1 then 'Active'
    when 2 then 'Job'
    when 3 then 'Pending'
    when 4 then 'Sales Lead'
    when 5 then 'Budget'
    when 6 then 'Change Order'
end as Status, 
Name, 
Address, 
ProjectType
FROM intranet.t_bidinfo
WHERE Division = 'TI'
AND EffectiveDate >= '2015-06-01'
AND Status IN (6,2)
ORDER BY EffectiveDate ASC
```